# `curl` not work and does not give any message

Tags: linux, curl, php

I have a script that checks addresses with curl
But why does some of the addresses like the one below hang?
What can I do to avoid it?
Check this address to understand more

```
curl https://10.10.34.36/test
```

my script :

```
$sites = file_get_contents('./sites.json');
$sites = json_decode($sites);
function get_html_title($html){
    preg_match("/\<title.*\>(.*)\<\/title\>/isU", $html, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
function get_redirect_target($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1); 
    
// The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 8); //timeout in seconds
    $headers = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $result = array("old"=>$url);
    // Check if there's a Location: header (redirect)
    if (preg_match('/^Location: (.+)$/im', $headers, $matches)){
        $result["new"] = trim($matches[1]); 
        $html = file_get_contents($result["new"]);
        $title = get_html_title($html);
        $result["title"] = trim($title); 
        return $result;
    }
       

    // If not, there was no redirect so return the original URL
    return "";
}
function get_redirect_final_target($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // follow redirects
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1); // set referer on redirect
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.6045.105 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)");
    curl_exec($ch);
    $target = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($target)
        return $target;

    return false;
}
$redirectsList = array();
foreach($sites as $key=>$site){
    $res=get_redirect_final_target($site->url);
    if($res!=$site->url){
    $html = file_get_contents($res);
    $title = get_html_title($html);
    $result["title"] = trim($title);     
    $newurl = ["old"=>$site->url,"new"=>$res,"title"=>$title];
        array_push($redirectsList,$newurl);
        $sites[$key]->url = $newurl['new'];
    }
}
file_put_contents('./sites5.json', json_encode($sites, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
echo '<table border="1">';
    echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>Old url</td>';
       echo '<td>New url</td>';
       echo '<td>Title</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
foreach($redirectsList  as $record){
    echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>'.$record['old'].'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.$record['new'].'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.$record['title'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

**my json file:**

```
[
    {
        "url": "https://10.10.34.36/test"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://google.com/"
    }
]
```

Comment: Your "script" isn't a script that we can test locally - it's a part of a larger script. Personally I'm not interested in your larger script so please don't be tempted to post that. Instead, post a _minimally verifiable example_ - something that runs standalone and demonstrates the issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to understand what you should provide

Comment: The whole script is just a few lines

Answer (score 2):

That's a private IP address. We cannot possibly know what kind of server you have there – but knowing how extremely widely `curl` is, how well-tested it is and how robust, I dare to diagnose this as:

Your server at 10.10.34.36 might simply not be alive, it might be hanging, or misbehaving, or your network setup is broken in some way (wrong proxy configured, no route to host…). All this is far more likely than `curl` nbot working correctly.

Comment: For example, imagine that I check 10 addresses with curl and this address is one of them...while checking this , my script crashes. Is it possible to skip this address and go to another address?

Comment: why would your script crash :O ?

Comment: When the script hits one of these addresses during run, the script hangs and stops working. Is it possible to send you the php script?

Comment: that's not a crash, that's just waiting for a response. two things: 1. curl has a lot of timeout options, you might want to read `man curl` about that. and 2. what has PHP to do with all this? If you're using PHP, why are you even working with curl at all? That makes no sense – use PHP's HTTP client library!

Comment: I added the script to the thread, please take a look

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely to "hang" - it's probably waiting for the other end to respond. I'm not going to try your test case, because my results will be different from yours and most other people's; 10.0.0.0/8 is a private range.

You can [limit the amount of time the curl library will spend trying to complete a request](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) with CURLOPT_TIMEOUT[_MS]

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work. I set it once to zero and once to 10, but the script hangs again. Please test it once

Comment: I can't test it on your infrastructure. Please update your question to show how you changed the code, what you measured and how you exited from the (not really) hung state. Better yet, provide a minimal, verifiable example.

Comment: How can I see the log script?